# How to get notified when android device starts rebooting

Tags: android, reboot

I'm developing an android application that has to get traffic statistics once a week. The problem is that if  user reboots his device, the statistics will be reloaded and the app will not be able to get statistics just by subtraction current value with an previous one. I was wondering if there exists some kind of listener for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no such way to find out (in a foolproof manner) that the device is rebooting.

Compunded by the fact that reboot can take place in many ways (from the UI - which is a procedural shutdown of the Android runtime, or from the shell using the "reboot" command which is Linux userland level call) you probably won't have enough time to do anything in your app once the reboot sequence has started.

Architecturally, you should always be in a situation where in a random reboot should not make your app lose critical data - i.e. always periodically saving your analytics data to file in internal storage etc.